# How can I run a test case from inside a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have files with:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SomeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ...


require 'test_helper'

class SomeOtherTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ...
```

How could I run them?, but not all other files in test folder. I am using Rails 2.3.14.

## Update

without reload the environment several times.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
ruby -I test test/unit/some_test.rb
ruby -I test test/unit/some_other_test.rb
```

Your test files may be another directory just use their path.

Comment: I forgot something in my question, sorry.